# Content in web view gets shrinking and disappears at the end while scrolling (marquee)?

Tags: android, html, android-webview, marquee

I am implementing a web view with marquee effect. I have a string and loaded it as HTML content by doing the below code.

```
String test= "this is a test. this is a test. this is a test. this is a test. this is a test. this is a test. this is a test. this is a test. this is a test. this is a test. this is a test. this is a test. this is a test. this is a test. this is a test. this is a test.";

            summary = "<html><FONT ><marquee behavior='scroll' direction='left' scrollamount=" + speed + ">"
                    + test + "</marquee></FONT></html>";
```

And I am loading this content in web view is shown below.

```
webviewScroll.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, summary, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

And below code to make the text to appear at the middile of page

webviewScroll.setPictureListener(new WebView.PictureListener() {
        int previousHeight;

```
    @Override
    public void onNewPicture(WebView w, Picture p) {
        int height = w.getContentHeight();
        webviewScroll.scrollTo(0, height / 2);

        webviewScroll.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Issue is that when the content is about to finish it gets shrink and disappear at last. The issue is happen only the content is about to finish and with large content. small content is not happening like this.

Below I have attached a screenshot of shrinking of content in a web view.

[image]

And below image shows marquee of content without shrinking in web view at the beginning.

[image]

Can anyone know why this is happening ?